# Toc LOF alignment issue in lyx

Tags: latex, lyx, tableofcontents

I'm doing my thesis in latex and using Lyx editor to achieve it. I want to place my TOC and LOF at the center of the page. I used

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\hfill}
```

but this is pushing toc caption to right.

How do I center lof in the same way?

Comment: Could you provide the community with a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem? By placing the ToC and/or LoF "at the center of the page", do you mean that you want the heading centred?

Comment: Hi @Werner, Yes i want only the heading to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert content *before* the Table of Contents/ToC title as well as *after*:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill<titlefont>}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\mbox{}}
```

`<titlefont>` represents any font switches you're interested in making. For adjustments to the List of Figures/LoF (List of Tables/LoT), use `\cftloftitlefont` and `\cftafterloftitle` (`\cftlottitlefont` and `\cftafterlottitle`).